# converting javascript to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this JavaScript functions that I want to convert to jquery but I can't understand jquery. It uses the `document.getElementsByName` a lot so I would like to know how to convert the `document.getElementsByName` into jquery.

```
function getElements(name){
    if (document.getElementsByName(name)[0].className == "visible"){
        document.getElementsByName(name)[0].className = "hidden";
    } else {
        if(document.getElementsByClassName('visible')[0] != null){
            document.getElementsByClassName('visible')[0].className = "hidden";
        }
        document.getElementsByName(name)[0].className = "visible";
    }
}
```

Comment: please try to do it by yourself first

Comment: What actually you trying to doing using JavaScript?

Comment: There are a lot of things that you can be told on this, but I think you need to start learning jQuery rather than asking questions. This should be a better place for starting jQuery (http://api.jquery.com/category/core/)

Comment: @NaveedButt the specific question is how to convert `getElementByName`. While a tutorial is a good idea, this question does not appear too broad to me.

Comment: `->` http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try with attribute selector...

```
 $('[name="'+name+'"]')  //for name selector
 $('.visible') //for class selector
```

Comment: glad it helped.... you can accept any of the answer if you think that helped... anyways happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 3):

You should try because when you try practicing you actually are learning:

- `document.getElementsByName` in jQuery `$("[name=Name]");`
- `document.getElementsById` in jQuery `$("#IdofElement");`
- `document.getElementsByClass` in jQuery `$(".ClassofElement");`

Here are some tutorials:

1. [jQuery for Beginners](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/246701/JQuery-for-Beginners)
2. [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/)
3. [Beginners Guide to jQuery](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-jquery)

Comment: Why are you not linking to the official jQuery tutorial (I don't mean the documentation)?

Comment: @EddieCastle You would go to google, and search **"how to get elements by name jQuery"** and then you would search **"How to get elements by class name jQuery"** then you would search **"how to add a class to a element jQuery"** Then you would put together what you have learned to create your functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the below syntax for your reference.

```
$('[name=tcol1]') // matches exactly 'tcol1'

$('[name^=tcol]') // matches those that begin with 'tcol'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
function getElements(name1){
    if ($("[name='" + name1 + "'").hasClass("visible")){
        $("[name='" + name1 + "'").removeClass("visible").addClass("hidden");
    } else {
        if($(".visible") != null){
            $(".visible").addClass("hidden");
        }
        $("[name='" + name1 + "'").removeClass("visible").addClass("visible");
    }
}
```

Comment: His original code replaces the class, you're adding a class without removing the old one. You'll end up with an element that's both hidden and visible, which is probably not desired.

Comment: This is exactly how I wanted the code thanks, with the exception that on line 8 it would be $("[name='" + name1 + "'").removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");

Comment: Nevermind, Barmar is right, it ends up with a hidden and visible class.

Comment: I added .removeClass("visible") to the end of line six and it worked